# Как на Google Maps отобразить выбранную из списка локацию?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps, wordpress-плагины

На сайте http://ua-company.com/prof-tech-oborudovanie?off=1

есть блок со списком предприятий по регионам. Выбирая определенный регион, слева от блока отображается список предприятий, ему принадлежащих. Плюс эти предприятия показываются на карте. Как на WP сделать такой список с привязкой к Картам? Я так понимаю, что для предприятий должен быть custom fields с мета-полями типа "Название предприятия", "Адрес (город, улица)"..., из которых берется информация для определения того или предприятия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, надо хранить информацию о предприятиях и их координатах в базе, скажем, в custom fields. Вывод на страницу можно сделать разными способами:

1. Создать карту с помощью API карт Google и добавить на нее столько маркеров, сколько нужно. Руководство Google [здесь](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=ru).
2. Использовать плагин [WP Google Maps](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/)
3. Использовать темы, "заточенные" под создание баз объектов с нанесением на карту, например [Javo Directory](http://javothemes.com/directory/demo2/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.